# How can I resolve the error QISkit Error: The same provider has already been registered!

Tags: programming, qiskit

I am writing a small algorithm to multiply two numbers using IBM's QISkit. The code  is below:

**times_shell.py**

```
import times

first = input("Enter a number with less than 7 digits.")
l1 = len(first)
second = input("Enter another number with less than " + str(8-l1) + " 
digits.")
l2 = len(second)
if l1 > l2:
    n = l1
    m = l2
else:
    first, second = second, first
    n = l2
    m = l1

prod = ("0")*(m+n)

while int(second) is not 0:
    second, prod = times.multiply(first, second, prod, n, m)
```

**times.py**

```
def multiply(first, second, product, n, m):

    a = QuantumRegister(m+n, "a") #accumulator
    b = QuantumRegister(m+n, "b") #holds multiplicand
    c = QuantumRegister(m, "c") #hold multiplier
    d = QuantumRegister(m, "d") #register with value 1
    cl = ClassicalRegister(m+n, "cl") #used for final output
    cl2 = ClassicalRegister(m, "cl2")
    qc = QuantumCircuit(a, b, c, d, cl, cl2, name="qc")

    for i in range(0, m+n):
        if product[i] == "1":  
            qc.x(a[m+n-(i+1)])

    for i in range(0, n):
        if first[i] == "1":
            qc.x(b[n-(i+1)])

    for i in range(0, m):
        if second[i] == "1":
            qc.x(c[m-(i+1)])

    qc.x(d[0])

    for i in range(0, m+n):
        createInputState(qc, a, m+n-(i+1), pie)

    for i in range(m):
        createInputState(qc, c, m-(i+1), pie)

    for i in range(0, m+n):
        evolveQFTState(qc, a, b, m+n-(i+1), pie) 

    for i in range(0, m):
        decrement(qc, c, d, m-(i+1), pie)

    for i in range(0, m):
        inverseQFT(qc, c, i, pie)

    for i in range(0, m+n):
        inverseQFT(qc, a, i, pie)

    for i in range(0, m+n):
        qc.measure(a[i], cl[i])

    for i in range(0, m):
        qc.measure(c[i], cl2[i])

    print(qc.qasm())

    register(Qconfig['APItoken'], Qconfig['url'])
    result = execute(qc, backend='ibmq_qasm_simulator', 
                  shots=1024).result()
    counts = result.get_counts("qc")
    print(counts)
    output = max(counts.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
    multiplier, accumulator = str(output).split(" ")

    print(multiplier)
    print(accumulator)

    return multiplier, accumulator
```

When I run it I get an error. The terminal output (the program output and the error) is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "times_shell.py", line 18, in <module> second, prod = 
    times.multiply(first, second, prod, n, m)
    File "D:\Projects\Quantum_Computing\IBM_Python\times.py", line 122, in 
    multiply
    register(Qconfig['APItoken'], Qconfig['url'])
    File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
    packages\qiskit\wrapper\_wrapper.py", line 56, in register
    _DEFAULT_PROVIDER.add_provider(provider)
    File "C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
    packages\qiskit\wrapper\defaultqiskitprovider.py", line 158, in 
    add_provider
    raise QISKitError("The same provider has already been registered!")
    qiskit._qiskiterror.QISKitError: 'The same provider has already been 
    registered!'
```

I'm not sure what the issue is here. Any help with this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you check the available backends from your credentials just in case? Qiskit provides such function to check.

Comment: Hi @cnada, I found a solution. I have elaborated upon the same in my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the solution is rather simple - simply move the registration bit of the code, i.e. the bit below, to the **times_shell.py** script.

```
register(Qconfig['APItoken'], Qconfig['url'])
```

This way I only register once, and can run my job multiple times. The successful results of my algorithm can be seen below:

Input:

```
Enter a number with less than 7 digits.1111
Enter another number with less than 4 digits.11
```

Output:

```
{'10 101111': 459, '10 001111': 565}
10
001111

{'01 000010': 15, '01 101110': 130, '01 011110': 197, '01 010110': 38, '01 110110': 
78, '01 000110': 58, '01 110010': 14, '01 100010': 50, '01 010010': 5, '01 100110': 
71, '01 111010': 21, '01 101010': 30, '01 001010': 19, '01 011010': 14, '01 111110': 
169, '01 001110': 115}
01

{'00 101101': 664, '00 110001': 1, '00 101001': 128, '00 001001': 7, '00 111001': 18, 
'00 011101': 8, '00 001101': 163, '00 100001': 4, '00 111101': 31}
00
101101
```

I hope this helps anyone facing similar issues.

Comment: Thanks for documenting all the issues you've run into, I'm certain this will help others as they learn!